# Javascript for loop yields wrong results

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, for-loop

```
for (var i in tokens) {
    var id = tokens[i].substring(0, tokens[i].indexOf('='));
    var name = tokens[i].substring(tokens[i].indexOf('=') + 1); 
    .                   
    .   
    .
    var button = document.createElement('button');
    button.id = id;
    $(button).addClass('friend-invite-button')
        .html('Invite')
        .click(function() {             
        $.ajax({ url: path + '/twitter/directmessage.php',
                     data: {'screen_name': name},
                     type: 'post',
                     success: function(output) { alert(output); }
                });
            }); 
}
```

The code above seems to attach the same value of variable 'name' to the click event. Every time i click on a button I get the same value in the alert, and that value is the last one i get by looping. Can you correct me please? my php file is below

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once('twitteroauth.php');
require_once('config.php');

$connection = new TwitterOAuth(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET);
$request_token = $connection->getRequestToken(OAUTH_CALLBACK);

$_SESSION['oauth_token'] = $token = $request_token['oauth_token'];
$_SESSION['oauth_token_secret'] = $request_token['oauth_token_secret'];

switch ($connection->http_code) {
  case 200:
    $options = array("screen_name" => $_POST["screen_name"], "text" => "message");
    $status = $connection->post('direct_messages/new', $options);
    echo $_POST["screen_name"];
    break;
  default:
    echo 'Could not connect to Twitter. Refresh the page or try again later.';
}
```

Comment: tokens=1849157244=79papakon&18404957=Kartesios&79528454=ai_katerina&125322383=TheKoulWay&275882593=lawgreece&18627400=nqtv&617386550=epamhellas&544153184=toxwni, on which I do a .split('&') before looping

Comment: Your click handler does access the values that were processed during the last iteration and set to the same variables. See [Javascript closure inside loops - simple practical example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example) on how to fix that.

Comment: If you're looping an array make sure to use a regular `for` loop, not a `for..in`

Comment: had no idea about this 'closure' trap, thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that the functions created on each iteration of your loop are going to look in the enclosing scope for the value of the `name` variable *when the function is called*.  This means that every one of those functions will end up using the value of `name` from the final iteration.

Consider the following simple example which illustrates what is going on here:

```
var functions = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    functions.push(function() {
        console.log(i);
    });
}
functions[0]();  // logs 3
```

So even though at a glance it looks like `functions[0]();` should log `0` since that was the value of `i` when `functions[0]` was created, it logs `3` because that is the value of `i` when the function is called.

One way to fix this is to use a closure that fixes the variables to their current value in each iteration:

```
function createClickHandler(path, name) {
    return function() {             
        $.ajax({ url: path + '/twitter/directmessage.php',
                 data: {'screen_name': name},
                 type: 'post',
                 success: function(output) { alert(output); }
                });
    };
};
for (var i in tokens) {
    .                   
    .   
    .
    $(button).addClass('friend-invite-button')
        .html('Invite')
        .click(createClickHandler(path, name)); 
}
```